# How to read string after dash?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

The code below, takes strings from column F and extract and converts it to a number in column G. I have a string 'J-60'(column F), which is currently not converting. The code should be able to extract any string before the (-), but if its (J-),then it should extract the string after the dash.

```
If InStr(Dn, "-") Then
  Dn.Offset(, 1) = Split(Dn, "-")(0)
 Else
  Select Case UCase(Left(Dn, 1))

Case "J"
    If UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "J+" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Num
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "J-" Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Num
    End If
    End Select
```

Please advice, where I may be going wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: **Where is the code that places a value in Num??**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have now updated my code, for further reference. Please advice, further. Thanks

Comment: To narrow this down, I would suggest: after `For Each Dn In Rng` put in `If Dn.Value = "J-60" then Stop`. Then you can cycle (F8) to see what's going on.

Comment: Not exactly sure why you are breaking things up like you are in your code, but the issue is that you are resetting the value of Num immediately after your Case "S" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement `If InStr(Dn, "-") Then` is too early.
You need better indenting and something like:

```
  If UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "J+" Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Num
  ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "J-" Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Num
  ElseIf InStr(Dn, "-") Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Split(Dn, "-")(0)
  End If
```

EDIT: code to handle 7889

```
  Dim sCase1$, vSplit As Variant
  sCase1 = ""
  vSplit = Split(Dn, "-")
  If UBound(vSplit) = 1 Then
    If IsNumeric(vSplit(0)) And IsNumeric(vSplit(1)) Then
      sCase1 = vSplit(0) & vSplit(1)
    End If
  End If
  If sCase1 <> "" Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = sCase1
  ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "J+" Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Num
  ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "J-" Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Num
  ElseIf InStr(Dn, "-") Then
    Dn.Offset(, 1) = Split(Dn, "-")(0)
  End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and response.  However, I have tried this approach earlier, but this then fails to convert 78-89--->7889, instead of 78.  I have tried adding in `[IsNumeric(Mid..]`, in between the `[Instr]` line of code, but that also does not seem to work. Any further advice, would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user3070072 - I've added (EDIT) code to handle 7889, but this could go on forever -- what are your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @dcromley for your solution, I manage to use your code to implement the following logic below, which works to solve the issue:

```
 s = UCase(Left(Dn, 2))
     If s = "J+" Or s = "J-" Then
   s = Right(Dn, Len(Dn) - 2)
   If IsNumeric(s) Then
     Dn.Offset(, 1) = Int(s)
   End If

ElseIf InStr(Dn, "-") Then
   Dn.Offset(, 1) = Split(Dn, "-")(0)
End If
```

Thanks

Comment: Nice followup - best to you.